# (MPX) Multi Pointer X on 10.04 and beyond?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, 10.04, xorg

I've read articles about Multi Pointer X on Ubuntu, and just wanted to know if it has got to a stable stage yet where it can easily be enabled on 10.04+?

If yes, how can I enable it?

Comment: It will become redundant in the next few releases with the move to Wayland. X can run on top of Wayland, however I do not know if it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is officially supported as of 10.04 so it will be stable and will be rather easy to set up from what I have read on [MPX on Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/MPX):

> Starting with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Ubuntu includes support for 
>   Multi-Pointer X. This allows the user to use multiple input devices 
>   simultaneously.

Actions:
`xinput list` This will show the currect setup.
`xinput create-master Second` This will create a 2nd pointer.
`xinput list` This will show the altered setup.

Based on the result of this you need to find all the required id's and do this (change all {}'s by their corresponding id's):

`sleep 1&&xinput reattach {mouse0_id} {2nd_pointer_id}&&xinput reattach {keyboard0_id} {2nd_keyboard_id}`

Comment: I've just tried this and it almost works correctly.  The only thing which does not work is the mouse which is moved, can do everything as normal, except move windows or resize windows.  Why is that?  I restarted and moved the other mouse, and the same thing happened, this time it was the other mouse which was able to do everything except move windows or resize windows...

Comment: I turned off desktop effects, and I can now resize windows and move windows with both mice.  However, if I have grabbed a window with one mouse, and try to move another window with the other mouse at the same time, the other mouse is not able to grab a window...  I don't think it is very stable at all...

Comment: @oshirowanen I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/688181 but it was called invalid. I'd advice filing a bug against xinput; when it sounds like a bug... ;-)

Comment: Also, why does the second pointer change based on the action of the first pointer, i.e. if the pointer is displaying a certain type of pointer by hovering over a link, or a textbox, or moving a window, the second pointer will display the same point which is a bit silly...  So, does a more stable version of this exist, as this version is not stable at all...

Comment: @oshirowanen not that I am aware of. This is the 'official' MPX package so it should be OK. It seems to not play nicely with compiz. I'd file a bug if I was you.

Comment: @Rinzwind, never filed a bug before, seems like a really complex process...