# How to use two mouse separately (two different pointers)

Tags: mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(MPX) Multi Pointer X on 10.04 and beyond?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45268/mpx-multi-pointer-x-on-10-04-and-beyond)

I have two monitors and two mice. There is only one mouse pointer which both mice control. But I want two different controls for the two different mice, hence two different pointers. Is there any solution available?

It is okay if one pointer works on only one monitor.